# my messages aren't displaying on my show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

i am making a simple chatroom application, the problem that i am having is that my messages aren't hitting the database when i check rails console. When i hit enter to submit my form the page reloads but no message displays. I permitted the message params in the messagesController `params.require(:message).permit(:body)` so i don't understand why my messages aren't showing up.

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_chatroom

  def create
    message = @chatroom.messages.new(message_params)
    message.user == current_user

    message.save
    redirect_to @chatroom
  end

  private

    def set_chatroom
      @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
    end

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

---

show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @chatroom.name %>
</p>

<div data-behavior='messages'>
    <% @chatroom.messages.order(created_at: :desc).limit(100).reverse.each do |message| %>
    <div><strong><%= message.user.username %></strong> <%= message.body %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<%= form_for [@chatroom, Message.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 1, class: "form-control", autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chatroom
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

chatrooms_controller.rb

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_chatroom, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /chatrooms
  # GET /chatrooms.json
  def index
    @chatrooms = Chatroom.all
  end

  # GET /chatrooms/1
  # GET /chatrooms/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /chatrooms/new
  def new
    @chatroom = Chatroom.new
  end

  # GET /chatrooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /chatrooms
  # POST /chatrooms.json
  def create
    @chatroom = Chatroom.new(chatroom_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @chatroom.save
        format.html { redirect_to @chatroom, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @chatroom }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @chatroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /chatrooms/1
  # PATCH/PUT /chatrooms/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @chatroom.update(chatroom_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @chatroom, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @chatroom }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @chatroom.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /chatrooms/1
  # DELETE /chatrooms/1.json
  def destroy
    @chatroom.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to chatrooms_url, notice: 'Chatroom was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_chatroom
      @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def chatroom_params
      params.require(:chatroom).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

---

chatroom_users_controller.rb

```
class ChatroomUsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    before_action :set_chatroom

    def create
        @chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
        redirect_to @chatroom
    end

    def destroy
        @chatroom_user = @chatroom.chatroom_users(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all
    redirect_to chatrooms_path
    end

    private

    def set_chatroom
        @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])

    end
end
```

Comment: Is there any message in the console?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma no there are no message in the console all the console say is  `Message.all
  Message Load (16.1ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messages are not being saved in the DB because of a validation error caused by blank `user_id`.

Check this line in `create` action of `MessagesController`:

```
message.user == current_user
```

It should be:

```
message.user = current_user
```

The first one is checking if `message.user` is equal to `current_user`; the second one **assigns** `current_user` to `message_user`.

Once you properly set `message.user` the message will be saved in the DB.